# Resize starling render zone without stretching the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I'm resizing an SWF object at runtime via JavaScript to fit the size of the window (100%x100%).

I need starling to render at the new size (most likely bigger than the swf's compile size), but to not stretch anything.

For instance:
-I have a 800x600 SWF
-SWF stage size after JavaScript resize (Starling.current.nativeStage) - 1000x800
-I add a DisplayObject at 900, 100
-Before render zone is changed, it would not be visible, since staring render zone covers only 800x600, regardless of the new stage size
-I need it to be visible at it's original size, at 900, 100.

How do I change the render zone of starling, without actually stretching the stage?

Comment: Try to change `Starling.current.viewPort`. “The viewport represents the visual area of the screen where starling is rendered.”